# Rubocop rule: Never use 'do' with multi-line 'while

Tags: ruby, while-loop, rubocop

I have the following code

```
  # colours a random cell with a correct colour
  def colour_random!
    while true do
      col, row = rand(columns), rand(rows)
      cell = self[row,col]
      if cell.empty? then
        cell.should_be_filled? ? cell.colour!(1) : cell.colour!(0)
        break
      end
    end
  end
```

it's not that important what's doing, although it should pretty obvious. The point is that Rubocop gives me a warning

> Never use 'do' with multi-line 'while

Why should I not do that? How should I do it then?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`while`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) is a keyword,so you don't need to pass a block. Without `do..end` it will work fine. The below is fine

```
  def colour_random!
    while true
      col, row = rand(columns), rand(rows)
      cell = self[row,col]
      if cell.empty? then
        cell.should_be_filled? ? cell.colour!(1) : cell.colour!(0)
        break
      end
    end
  end
```

*`while`* is a keyword, and if you pass a block to it, like `do..end`, it still works as you asked it to do, by not throwing any error, rather just a **warning**. But it could be dangerous if you try to pass a `Proc` or `Method` object to it, and dynamically try to convert it to a **block** using **`&`** keyword, as we do generally. That means

```
# below code will work as expected just throwing an warning.
x = 2
while x < 2 do
  #code
end
```

But if you try to do by mistake like below

```
while &block # booom!! error
```

The reason is `while` is a keyword, which don't support any `to_proc` method to satisfy your need. So **it can be dangerous**.

**Ruby style guide** also suggested that [Never use `while/until condition do` for *multi-line* `while/until`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax)

I think the reason is as *Nobuyoshi Nakada* said in the [*mailing list*](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/178594#781972)

`loop` is a `kernel` method which takes a **block**.  A **block** introduces new *local variable scope*.

```
  loop do
    a = 1
    break   
  end   
  p a #=> causes NameError
```

`while` doesn't.

```
  while 1
    a = 1
    break   
  end
  p a #=> 1
```

Comment: 1. Is this really the block? I cannot do this: `i=0; pr1={i+=1}; while(i<10) &pr1`. 2. **Never use 'do' with multi-line 'while** it sounds like it's something dangerous. So... why it can be dangerous?

Comment: @DarekNędza 1. *Is this really the block?* Yes it is really block - **do..end**. 2. What you said, Yes you can do that, that is called *single line*.[*while can also appear in modifier position, either in a single-line statement or in a multi-line statement using a begin/end block.*](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) 3. *Never use 'do' with multi-line 'while it sounds like it's something dangerous. So... why it can be dangerous?* - That answer I don't have, if you have please share.

Comment: 1. So why I cannot convert proc to the *block* (using `&`)? I can do this in other methods like `map`, `each` etc. **do..end** might be just syntactic sugar. As for my code snipped I don't mean doing one-liner, but if `&` convert proc to block it is prove that while takes block. As for now, I cannot prove it.

Comment: So much edit blinking on my screen! Well, I've just asked "if `while do end` takes block or not. I haven't thought about how it can be dangerous in this situation. You worked up good answer although! So "+1".

Comment: "Ruby style guide also suggested" ... yeah, I found it later that Rubocop actually goes by this rules. So it's more like "Ruby style guide suggests" and "Rubocop also suggests".

Comment: @OndrejJanacek As far I remember, Rubocop is made by same person so (s)he used *his/her* style guide.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby actually has a shortcut for `while true`: [the `loop` statement](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).

```
def colour_random!
  loop do
    col, row = rand(columns), rand(rows)
    cell = self[row,col]
    if cell.empty? then
      cell.should_be_filled? ? cell.colour!(1) : cell.colour!(0)
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know why one would use `while true` when `loop do` is available.  Maybe it's from years of C/C++ coding.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I guess so. The `loop` statement is quite uncommon among the variety of different programming languages, however `while true` has no functional drawbacks. It's just a question of beauty ;-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland [`Loop vs while`](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/178594#781972) - you can read it. My choice will be always `while`, not a `loop`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Looking into my profile would tell you that my background is C# ;)

Comment: Good point, @Arup, but aren't there many situations where it makes no difference, and some situations where you want a block, to keep its local variables away from prying eyes?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes... obviously there should be.. Otherwise language designer probably may not keep this item present in Ruby.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't know if I'm right but I think Ruby's `while` can be transformed into C's `while`without too much effort, while doing the same with `loop` may make some *troubles*(speed issues).

Comment: The overhead being the creation of and calls to a block.